# What is _MULTI_THREADED in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c-preprocessor

I saw some examples and programs uses this pre-proccessor definition:

```
 #define _MULTI_THREADED
```

What is it and why should we use it?

Edited: What is the best reference to Study About C++ Multi_threading?

Comment: I would recommend this book: http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it before any inclusion to enable some multi thread features.

> The **_MULTI_THREADED** preprocessor value is used to indicate that your application uses the kernel threads model. The preprocessor value can also be used by other parts of the system to create threadsafe macros. For example, the fputc() macro of ILE C can use the _MULTI_THREADED preprocessor value. You should always define the _MULTI_THREADED preprocessor value in source files that run in kernel threaded jobs. [1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/rzah4mpv.htm)

Comment: Thanks A Milion :-*
Is there any complete reference in multithreading in C++?

Comment: @user2982229: I don't know, multi threading is a broad concept. BTW, C++ has a full support thread library + a [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: Note, however, that `_MULTI_THREADED` is compiler-specific. The quote above is from IBM's documentation for their compiler; it may or may not be correct for other compilers.

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro used to access implementation-specific forms of threading. This is not portable. The better way is `#include <thread>`.

I've heard good things about "C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading" 
by Anthony Williams but haven't read it myself.